# How to verify again the user when he has already signed-in for gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am developing a ROR app.
Users can log in using google accounts via 'omniauth-google-oauth2'.
They can also delete their accounts.

When deleting accounts, I expect the user to be verified again.
The traditional way is to delete the account after inputing the correct password. How should this be done under 'omniauth-google-oauth2' or Omniauth, since there will be no password?

Comment: Why do you say `The traditional way is to delete the account after inputing the correct password` ?

Comment: When using gem like Devise, we can ask the user to confirm password again. This will not be the case in Omniauth since there is no password. So "the traditional way" means in the case of Devise. Sorry for the confusion.